# Why the select syscall only has a upper limit on the file descriptors and not a lower limit?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, multiplexing

In the

```
int select(
          int nfds,
          fd_set *readfds,
          fd_set *writefds,
          fd_set *exceptfds,
          struct timeval *timeout);
```

syscall, `nfds` is the largest file descriptor we are interested in among all the file descriptors that are set in the bit maps. I think this is meant for efficiency so that the implementation doesn't have to scan thru all file descriptors in the system. If that is the case, then why doesn't this syscall allow us to pass an argument to specify the minimum file descriptor of interest as well ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but the file descriptors tend to be small numbers, so maybe it was just that specifying the lower limit wouldn't help much typically.

Comment: That is what appears to be simplest explanation. But there could be a more technical reason.

Answer (score 1):

File descriptor numbering is per process not per system as you say. So they start at zero each time, thus not much use to have a lower limit.

Comment: yeah i got that concept clarified yesterday.

Comment: And you can move them around with `dup2`. So a lower limit would be redundant.